# How to match return of tomorrow with factor of today more efficiently in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm handling financial data, and want to match the return of the future to the factor of today. My data table consists of 13 columns as follows.
[image]

In this case, 'ret' is return, and 'me' is a factor. Thus, for example, I want rt+1's value in April 1986 to have -22.755625(=ret value of May 1986), and rt+1's value in May 1986 to have -1.022513(=ret value of June 1986). Since I have to repeat this task 'permno' by 'permno', I sort the data by 'year' and 'month', then tried the code below.

```
double_sorted['rt+1'] = np.NaN
for permno in permno_list:
    target = double_sorted[double_sorted['permno'] == permno]
    double_sorted.iloc[target.iloc[:-1].index, 12] = target['ret'].values[1:]
```

However, my code took a very long time. Is there any other way to improve the performance of the task?

Comment: You don't have 1986-02. What should be the value of `rt+1` for 1986-01? `NaN` or the value of 1986-03? (for `permno==10000.0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a vectorized operation

```
double_sorted['ret+1'] = double_sorted.sort_values(['permno', 'year', 'month'])\
.groupby('permno').ret.shift(-1)
```